# Cron is sending emails on failure, don't know why

Tags: email, cron

My cron is sending emails on error, which is great, but there's two problems with it.

1. I don't remember setting it up, so also don't remember where it's set up.
2. It's sending to an nonexistent email address. I only see the email in the "from" email address as a "delivery failed" email.

In my `var/log/mail.log` I see the following:

```
Nov  7 06:25:04 vandenberg postfix/pickup[2527]: B62C3140B94: uid=0 from=<root>
Nov  7 06:25:04 vandenberg postfix/cleanup[8315]: B62C3140B94: message-id=<20161107052504.B62C3140B94@SERVER.WORKGROUP>
Nov  7 06:25:04 vandenberg postfix/qmgr[22166]: B62C3140B94: from=<root@mail.nonexistent.com>, size=738, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  7 06:25:06 vandenberg postfix/smtp[8317]: B62C3140B94: to=<root@mail.nonexistent.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[blabla]:587, delay=1.8, delays=0.18/0.1/0.46/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1478496306 g184sm7156932wme.23 - gsmtp)
Nov  7 06:25:06 vandenberg postfix/qmgr[22166]: B62C3140B94: removed
```

Both `mail.nonexistent.com` entries are the same address.

The email I see is as follows:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     root@mail.nonexistent.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: 159949072 DNS type 'mx' lookup of mail.nonexistent.com responded with code NXDOMAIN
Domain name not found: mail.nonexistent.com


----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=from:to:subject:mime-version:content-transfer-encoding:message-id
         :date;
        bh=4yOG03cMbyTGx1B7oNyAICwDj42G7bYEMTzfRihbet0=;
        b=T6I62wxHoVle9UPqoQOx8WdcVhZXHKQAuj94IuPnoQ1T+pPrLl/6dwQreJhRN7An9r
         i+Uz2iHwCPGalVQsYxlVwl1RDFSGRUnsJlq9dLDiww64Px1h/axXHoWCwOya/OWXbO1C
         eADVVU1FAyJVH3+K47WZXU95+p13rW+eg9fLppRHPI+xpeRSOarHjwF8bYKPD3bPA1qn
         NCeZ6vbK8IaPUBUoGpKJduqZZ8/85aPsq/cHAyXESxllcw25HbgA8HGQmuJRyhwUzvZf
         37kFnylOHqKSF/BkjZBUcNnZrp+jW8QoDr5/8yQjWK3Qrb1uKTHI5gm/rK815g2dyG3R
         vnfg==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:from:to:subject:mime-version
         :content-transfer-encoding:message-id:date;
        bh=4yOG03cMbyTGx1B7oNyAICwDj42G7bYEMTzfRihbet0=;
        b=k1iyt+Tx4HhSyhYV/wCvep1vRi+sOk/j8e0B3nFQdwgglBHlnWiRsCpwmU8vVGw0XF
         h9Gggs6s8u68nw+HCzg5tcNH/76UAvGVr7YcT/cEkOzaMOULEiGgUQ/BTI5ghbpRoXX/
         28u6iKzCFlRp/VhbJRQ3mPASoHlw+w53Q1krTyC4as3VSN2rGhdcDG1MjtDdwyjB9PzO
         WW7oY8DuRJIHkKsGTiq+MIMs+ys8/1av0/nM5ZveGsypbMIJXdHr4HlCrkVgDhRHwey5
         X2+ogCqfPub+fpqazlHVLdAWSbVAc9OW88wMsIRloMWFSWCXmoJ3JoJoUKUZiHZZIvrE
         G/Hg==
X-Gm-Message-State: ABUngvf6UR5IHY4bkUC8h2qfQThTw4RCCPw1/fLjwvhZ9ZYFdfWj5UPewkIAcRpAdP7RfA==
X-Received: by 10.28.107.129 with SMTP id a1mr6680384wmi.90.1478496306482;
        Sun, 06 Nov 2016 21:25:06 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <xxx@gmail.com> // This is how I got this email.
Received: from SERVER.WORKGROUP (d5c5247e.ftth.concepts.nl. [213.197.36.126])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id g184sm7156932wme.23.2016.11.06.21.25.05
        for <root@mail.vandenbergit.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 06 Nov 2016 21:25:05 -0800 (PST)
From: Cron Daemon <xxx@gmail.com>
X-Google-Original-From: root@mail.nonexistent.com (Cron Daemon)
Received: by SERVER.WORKGROUP (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id B62C3140B94; Mon,  7 Nov 2016 06:25:04 +0100 (CET)
To: root@mail.nonexistent.com
Subject: Cron <root@vandenberg> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20161107052504.B62C3140B94@SERVER.WORKGROUP>
Date: Mon,  7 Nov 2016 06:25:04 +0100 (CET)

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
gzip: stdin: file size changed while zipping
```

The contents of `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` are:

```
#!/bin/sh

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Where could this email-sending behavior be configured, and how would it get the `root@mail.nonexistent.com` email-address?

Note, hostname is set to an actually existent address, and doesn't seem to be used.

```
root@vandenberg:/etc/cron.daily# hostname
existent.com
SERVER
```

Comment: Typically system cron output is sent to `root@hostname` (what *is* your hostname?) and it is also fairly common that the mailbox for the local `root` user is forwarded to an actual person by means of /etc/aliases

Comment: @HBruijn It's not sent to root@hostname, see my edit. Also, it's not forwarded in aliases.

Comment: did you check `/etc/logrotate.conf` and all cron config files in `/etc/default`, `/etc/sysconfig`. In general you can `grep -Ri nonexistent.com /etc/`

Comment: Check postfix's configuration for [myorigin](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myorigin)

Comment: BTW rather than hiding it, you should fix your logrotate error, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32045778/473915).  You'll need the `--verbose` flag to figure out which logrotate configuration entry to add the `delaycompress` option to.

Comment: The brute way would be to `grep -ir "root@mail.nonexistent.com" /etc` and see if that mail pops up somewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comments from Daniel and phillip-zyan k lee-stockmann pointed me in the right direction.

After using `grep -Ri nonexistent.com /etc/` one file popped out, [`/etc/mailname`](https://wiki.debian.org/EtcMailName).

It seems that this file defines the hostname for all mail applications on debian, so I changed it. It seems like this solved the problem.